# Simple HttpClient test failing on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, .net-4.5, async-await, system.net

When executing this simple little test on Mono (3.2.1) on Mac OS X it never prints any response to the console but instead says `Shutting down finalizer thread timed out.`
Is there something wrong with this code or is my Mono misbehaving?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace VendTest
{
  class MainClass
  {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.HttpClientCall();
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        HttpClient client;

        public Client()
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async void HttpClientCall()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://vendhq.com");
            string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should almost never use `async void` methods and this is one reason why. Your `Main()` will end before `HttpClientCall()` actually completes. And since exiting from `Main()` terminates the whole application, nothing will get printed.

What you should do is to change your method into `async Task` and `Wait()` for it in your `Main()`. (Mixing `await` and `Wait()` can often lead to deadlocks, but it's the right solution *for console applications*.)

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Client().HttpClientCallAsync().Wait();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async Task HttpClientCallAsync()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://vendhq.com");
        string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseAsString);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this obscure piece of knowledge! now it works :)